# React: how to initialize reducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Hi I'm trying to learn useReducer to use it in future case but I ran into an error.
When I'm trying to initialize it I can't pass an initial state

here is my code :

```
const initialState = {
  count: 0,
};

const reducer = () => {
  console.log('hello');
};

const Test = (): ReactElement => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return <div>test</div>;
};
```

I get an error on my initialState who say :

```
Argument of type '{ count: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'
```

I precise that I use typescript

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error. It was because my reducer function was returning nothing